# Ban across entire system based on ssh attempts

Tags: ssh, http, nginx, blocking, fail2ban

I have fail2ban set up to ban anyone who tries to connect via. ssh without my certificate.

I currently have a list of 1886 banned addresses (and counting), majority of which originate from China. China is not my target audience for my nginx web server, so I am able to block the entire country with `geoip_country`, however I would also like to specifically deny access to http/https/git from those specifically on the ban list too.

I have these two configurations:

```
[nginx-http-auth]
enabled  = true
filter   = nginx-http-auth
port     = http,https
logpath  = %(nginx_error_log)s
maxretry = 3
bantime  = -1
```

and

```
[sshd]
enabled  = true
port     = ssh
logpath  = %(sshd_log)s
backend  = %(sshd_backend)s
maxretry = 3
findtime = 600
bantime  = -1
```

Is there a way I can combine these two together? Ban anywhere, apply block anywhere?
I'm not quite sure how to do any tests, given if I ban myself I'd get locked out (static ip)?

Comment: There are numerous VPN providers that would allow you to tweak and test your server configuration without banning your own static IP address

Comment: @Ramhound Ah, that's an idea!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can combine these two together? Ban anywhere, apply block anywhere?

Fail2ban has several `*-allports` actions (default is multiport), so you can simply set it as `banaction`.
There is also a default substitution variable [banaction_allports](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/884cbbd6e17dd97a87a5c6f7527c0512698ea5d2/config/jail.conf#L209) in your `jail.conf`, so normally it would be enough to overwrite `banaction` with that in your `jail.local` for jail or default section:

```
[DEFAULT]
# banaction = iptables-allports
banaction = %(banaction_allports)s

# [sshd]
# # banaction = iptables-allports
# banaction = %(banaction_allports)s
```

Some multiport actions allows set ports like `0:65535`, so you can also use `port = 0:65535` in corresponding jails (but allports would ban also in all protocols etc).

> given if I ban myself I'd get locked out (static ip)?

You can add your (dynamic?) IP to `ignoreip` of fail2ban to avoid ban during your tests, also temporary using command line:

```bsh
# add 192.0.2.1 to be ignored in sshd:
fail2ban-client set sshd addignoreip 192.0.2.1

# remove 192.0.2.1 to be ignored in sshd:
fail2ban-client set sshd delignoreip 192.0.2.1
```